# Need to hold mobile ad unit at bottom of screen

Tags: css, mobile

Im trying to implement a `320x50` mobile ad for my mobile version of my website.  I want the ad to span be the entire `width` of a mobile device.  However the ad is showing up small and not the entire `width` of my iphone, and it scrolls along with content.

I use this code in my web page to call the mobile css

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="mobile2.css" />
```

And then in the css I have tried

```
div#mobilead {
  width:100%;
}
```

I need the ad to show up at the bottom of the screen and stay in place even while scrolling.
any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Here is the entire code as requested

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="mobile2.css" />

</head>

<body>


 <div id="mobileB">  
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- TWF_mobile_banner_adsense -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:50px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="6479374699"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

and then the css

```
#mobileB {
    position: absolute; 
bottom:0;
left:0;
z-index: 99; 
width:100%; 
height:50px
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're getting this CSS as the most priority one? How big is the ad showing now?

I would start by adding static height to the div as well, if you're sure it's always the same height.

Comment: When I zoom completely out on the website, the ad is tiny.  relative to the 728x90 banner its less than half the size of that

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share your html structure as well? This is needed because it depends on your div structure there is a thing called property inheritance in CSS so when you're dealing with positioning it is actually relevant to know not only the specific object's properties but its parents as well.

Now from what I see, I can't see any reason why it shouldn't scroll with the content. I am not a pro but I think your best chance would be to use fixed positioning. Based on where you want the ad to appear, you will have to set specific coordinates. For example if you would like it to appear at the top right corner as a sort of "sticky" div, this is what you could do:

```
position: fixed; 
top: 0px; 
right: 0px; 
z-index: 99; 
width:100%; 
height:50px;
```

I am sorry, I didn't see that you mentioned that you need it positioned at the bottom. In that case you could do it like this:

```
position: fixed; 
bottom:0;
left:0;
z-index: 99; 
width:100%; 
height:50px
```

At any case, whatever you decide and what you need, you should be able to achieve by playing with top/bottom/left/right, position:fixed and z-index. :) Good luck!

Comment: hmmm i tried this and the ad is still tiny. and its at the very bottom of the web page so have to scroll just to see it.  I think the problem is I am dealing with the size relative to the desktop version.  meaning a banner of 320 width is not taking up the entire width of the screen.

Comment: as I said, please post your whole HTML structure (with css) that is relevant to this specific DIV - meaning every DIV that encompasses the div for ads. The problem could be there.

Comment: here is a working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/shalikas/53VHp/

Don't forget to adjust @media max width in accordance to your device (I had to change it since I can't test it on my phone). 

If it still doesn't work, I would assume it is something with the adsense itself though it should work. 

Oh and sorry, I mixed absolute positioning with fixed positioning. I changed it in the original post in case others come across the same problem. Tell me if it works.

Comment: thanks, however the ad is still showing up small...the width is only about 30% of the phone screen, and the height is super small.  Is it because the screen is so zoomed out?